# Java drawing a graph with Y coordinates increasing up

Tags: java, user-interface, graph, drawing, coordinates

Java has a really non-intuitive coordinate scale where the origin (0,0) is at the top left and the Y coordinate increases **downwards**.

Normally graphs have (0, 0) at the bottom left and the Y coordinate increases **upwards**.

This makes drawing points and shapes in relation to each other in a graph very difficult.

How can I change it so that the origin is at (0, 0) and Y goes upward?

Thanks

Comment: are you looking to create a custom graph drawing utility?

Answer (score 1):

This is not "non-intuitive" if you study display hardware since the screen coordinates also begin in the upper left quadrant.

The solution is to separate your model from your view a la Model-View-Controller, to have your model's coordinates oriented as you see fit, and to write methods that translate model to view and back again where needed.